# Page wont load and server crashes during PHP while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to run a php script that says basically, whilst two cells in my MySQL database are empty (t_trailerarrival and t_endsort), do something.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
// Start Session, include authentication and dBConnection script
session_start();
include 'dbcon.php';
include 'sql_actuals.php';
$current_time = date("G"); 

while($query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] == NULL && $query10_row['a_endsort'] == NULL) {
    echo "Trailer Arrival";
}
```

The $queryx_row['abc'] are all in the sql_actuals script that is included into this script.

For some reason, every time i run this script - my browser wont load the result (just loads for ever) and then my website at windows azure seems to crash and take a few minutes to restart.

Could someone please advise if there is a massively obvious error with my script? or point me at what the possible issue could be.

Many thanks in advance.

FYI, i have tried adding a line `sleep(1);` so that it gave the server it runs off a delay before having to run the program again but no luck.

Comment: Doesn't it just enter an infinite loop? If your server actually crashes you'll want to check the error log. if PHP times out then you're still good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually doing anything in your while statement except echoing a line.

Therefore

```
$query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] == NULL
```

and

```
$query10_row['a_endsort'] == NULL
```

are always true and never changing, and it will never exit the while loop.  You need to put exit criteria in the while loop, such as:

```
$i=0;
while(($query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] == NULL 
        && $query10_row['a_endsort'] == NULL ) 
       || $i==10) {
    $i++;
    echo "Trailer Arrival";
}
```

Although, logically speaking, you still need to run the query data.

**** Edit ****
Based upon your feedback, this doesn't sound like a while loop at all, but rather an `if` statement you need (with multiple `elseif` s).

```
if ($query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] == NULL && $query10_row['a_endsort'] == NULL){
   echo "Trailer Arrival";
} elseif ($query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] == NULL  && $query10_row['a_endsort']){
   echo "End Sort";
} elseif ($query9_row['a_trailerarrival']  && $query10_row['a_endsort']){
   echo "First Van";
}else {
  // fourth condition:
  // $query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] != NULL &&  $query10_row['a_endsort'] == NULL
}
```

I included a fourth condition when $query9_row isn't null, and $query10_row is null.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand fully. I understand what you are saying to the extent that whilst both query9 and 10 are true, the query will while loop will continue to run but as soon as data is entered into the database under a_endsort or a_trailerarrival, the idea was that this would end the while statement?

Comment: I dont know if i am using the best method to achieve what im after..

I basically have 3 boxes. Within the first box i want to display "Trailer arrival" if both query9 and 10 are NULL. However, if query9 == NULL && query10 != NULL then i want to display "End sort". And if both query9 and 10 != NULL then i want it to display "first van".

this was working kind of okay when i had a jQuery function on my page saying basically :
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{ 
$('#box1_top').load('b1_top.php').fadeIn("slow");
},1000);

I basically need the same effect but within the php script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments - I did originally have that setup where I just had a load of if/else if{} statements but the problem is that the box content needs to change the moment something is entered into the database. If/elseif works if the page is refreshed and the script is ran again but I need a solution that allows the conditions to run constantly , incase one of the conditions were to change. If that makes sense :S! That's why I thought a while statement would be best?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have to have Javascript to do that.  That is why the jQuery worked for you before; it is real time and client based.  The php will only update when the server receives a http: request.  You could perform an AJAX call to periodically query the result, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for clarifying that for me. I'll have a bash with jQuery instead then and not waste any more time trying with php! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You are never closing the while loop.

```
while($query9_row['a_trailerarrival'] == NULL && $query10_row['a_endsort'] == NULL) {
    echo "Trailer Arrival";
}
```

Without modifying the while conditions during a while statement, once you start, you'll never stop. Therefore hanging the script and server.